# Angular-JS : selected values not getting correctly when submit from add\remove model

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs

in one of my project i've a scenario in which i've to use one add/remove model in which we can add certain values from right to left also we can remove, change the order up and down of the selected values. The add/remove model is a plugin which is been given like as below

```
<div class="addRemove">
<select size="5" multiple></select>
<select size="5" multiple></select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

On using the above code we will get a add remove model upon on selecting an item at right section and  clicking on to **(<<)** button will add to the left section similarly we can remove it by selecting the item and clicking **(>>)**, also we can change the order of the selected items by clicking the **Up** and **Down** buttons.

we cant access the add, remove, up, down button clicking functions, since it is been defined within the plugin and have no access to it.

we are using angular-js for value binding, a similar code i've done below, but here add and remove button click method is all present (up and down implementation is not done) but without through that methods on clicking the submit button how can we get the **selected list** with the **order no**.

**[JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4962/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<section class="container">
    <div>
        <select  ng-model="data.selected" id="leftValues" size="5" multiple></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="btnLeft" ng-click="btnLeftClick()" >&lt;&lt;</button>
        <button id="btnRight" ng-click="btnRightClick()">&gt;&gt;</button>
        <button id="btnUp" >UP</button>
        <button id="btnDown" >DOWN</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="data.notselected" id="rightValues" ng-options="i.name for i in items" size="4" multiple>

        </select>
    </div>

</section>

<button id="btnRight" ng-click="btnSubmitClick(data.selected)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);

app.controller("Controller", ['$scope', function($scope){

//// btnLeftClick() &  btnRightClick () METHODS IS NOT ACCESSIBLE /////   
$scope.btnLeftClick = function()
{
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
}

$scope.btnRightClick = function()
{
    var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
}
//// btnLeftClick() &  btnRightClick () METHODS IS NOT ACCESSIBLE /////

$scope.btnSubmitClick = function(selected)
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(selected));
}

$scope.items = [{
        id: 'id1',
        order: '',
        name: 'Item 1'},
    {
        id: 'id2',
        order: '',
        name: 'Item 2'},
    {
        id: 'id3',
        order: '',
        name: 'Item 3'},
    {
       id: 'id4',
        order: '',
        name: 'Item 4'}];

  }]);
```

Comment: is this a jquery plugin? You can see selected item via $scope.data.selected in controller is it enough for you?

Comment: it is giving values of $scope.data.selected as undefined after i pushed items to left and click the submit.....

Comment: because you just bind data.selected to select which means you should select it for getting data otherwise you just push them as options...

Comment: can you please show me that within that jsfiddle

Comment: there can be many ways to do it. problem is if there is any dependency of any plugin can I edit your function (btnRightClick, btnLeftClick...)

Comment: nope....we cant access those methods....